# REST APIs to do CRUD operations on Azure DevOps board external integrations

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on a project that requires me to do CRUD operations on top of Azure DevOps Board's External integrations.

For example, connecting ADO with github.

From debugging the UI of ADO i found ADO to be consuming `https://dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_settings/boards-external-integration` URL.

Are these API's open to public? if not what is the way arround?

[image]

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no Public Rest APIs can do CRUD operations on Github Connections in Project Settings.

For more details, you can refer to this ticket: [How to automate GitHub connections from Azure DevOps when any repo will created into GitHub](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/How-to-automate-GitHub-connections-from/10032726?q=github)

You can check the Browser F12 to get the backend API when connecting to Github Repo.

[image]

It will use the following API to do the action:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery
```

I have checked the API. When we connect to Github manually on the page, it takes extra steps to authenticate Github instead of providing information in the body of the API. Therefore, if you use an unofficial API, there will be certification restrictions.

Therefore, there is currently no method to implement CRUD operations using the API.

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.